# How to import sth from cordova package in Meteor1.3

Tags: cordova, meteor, import

As you know, Meteor 1.3 introduce the import & export syntax, when I use a cordova object before, I use it directly, but now I should use import, I can not find a spec for how to import it, just like npm package you just import it using its package name, and meteor package you just import meteor/meteorPackageName. So

How to import sth from a cordova package in Meteor 1.3?